# Is bootstrap 3 mainly for mobile designs?

Tags: bootstrapper

Can we still use bootstrap 3 to design websites for pcs/laptops? They say it's mobile first, so I don't know, can I still use bootstrap 3 just like bootstrap 2.x?

Comment: Short answer: absolutely!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

"[Mobile First](http://www.lukew.com/ff/entry.asp?933)" is just a way to think about the design process. You start with limited space which basically forces you to focus on the important stuff. You would then work your way up from there.

Comment: So it's pretty much the same way? Same 12 grids design? I just use it like I use bootstrap 2.x?

Comment: It still has a gird system. I'm not sure if it's identical to the one before it but the documentation is here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid